# Prevent Record Update Synchronously via External HTTP Call

Tags: apex, callout, before-trigger

I'm integrating Salesforce with an external system, and updates to records in Salesforce need to be kept in sync with the system. If the request to the external system fails, the update in SF should fail as well, and I want this to happen synchronously because allowing the update and then rolling it back would be odd behavior. I know synchronous callouts aren't allowed in triggers, so I was wondering what my options are.

Comment: The records are inserted /updated via salesforce UI?

Comment: The records will initially be inserted via an integration app that uses the SOAP API, but will be updated via the UI.

Comment: You would need to use an External Object if you really want synchronous behavior, and then the data wouldn't be in Salesforce at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be comfortable in creating custom lightning components or visualforce page then its possible.

We cannot do a callout after a DML, but can do a DML after a callout.

So we will create a lightning component or VF that will facilitate the update of that record.

The save button is not a standard save button, but a button that calls custom Apex. In your apex method, you will do a callout to the 3rd party system and update 3rd Party Record. If the callout is a success then do the update to your SF record. If not show an error message to the end user.

Comment: Could either of those be utilized in tandem with the regular UI that's available for objects? I'm not sure what those two entail.

Comment: I dont think you can do it via standard UI, you have to go custom.